# Run background process in flutter,when app closed to show Notification and Hit API,

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I 've tried `background_fetch: '^0.1.0'`

and alarm_manager package, but when the app is closed, it removed from the recent apps, and it does not work.
I need to hit API every 15 min n show Notification if data is there

when App is closed
any solution without writing Native code.
I don't know iOS development, I know Android
I don't need  Firebase Push Notification

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124

Comment: check this article on medium

Comment: That medium article does not apply to what he is doing. It's using the callback from the geofencing service of iOS. He wants to wake up his app at a set interval. Something you can't do on iOS. Please see the below answer.

Answer (score 3):

Background fetch is not controllable on iOS by the app developer. It is controlled by the OS. You sign up for "Background App refresh".

Once your app has registered for Background App refresh. The OS will awaken your app periodically at it's discretion to let you do some work. Then your app is put right back into sleep again. Depending on how long it's been scene the user opened your app it may have been purged from ram. If you are purged from ram it's very likely you won't be awakened again until the user opens your app or is plugged into power and charging the phone.

From https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch

> iOS can take some hours or even days to start a consistently scheduling background-fetch events since iOS schedules fetch events based upon the user's patterns of activity.

iOS favors Push notifications to save battery life. All push notifications run though apples APN service. [image]

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server
This saves on battery life as only one constant connection has to remain open on the device to Apple. Instead of multiple connections from many servers.